# What is a good way in Google AppScript to enable/disable UI elements based on a configuration

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a good way to enable/disable UI elements of a Google AppScript AddOn based on a configuration without wrapping every UI element in a conditional statement.
At the moment I have something like this:

```
var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();

if(contains('textSection')){
 var textsection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Some Feature ');

  if(contains('someTextA')){
  textsection.addWidget(CardService.newDecoratedText()
    .setText("some text A")
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('myfunction.functionOne'))
    .setTopLabel("Click"));

  }
  if(contains('someTextB')){
    textsection.addWidget(CardService.newDecoratedText()
      .setText("some text")
      .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('myfunction.functiontwo'))
      .setTopLabel("Click"));
  }

  card.addSection(textsection)
}
 
return card.build();
```

However this is not very good to read and error prone. I would like to encapsulate the definition of all UI elements and the decision which one is visible/available based on a specific configuration.

Comment: Cards need to be built before they are displayed, you could define events that would update the displayed card [as seen here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/navigation#navigation_best_practice) but at some point you'll still need to validate how to build it. This could be a good feature request, you could submit it directly to Google using this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206

Comment: hm it would be nice to just add all widgets and cards without conditional but when added also assign an ID to it, and then have a function which builds those cards, but first checks a config if the already added widget is part of it and removes it if not.
Something like that, but the Cardbuilder has no method to cycle through the already added sections